# Error Conpressed Depth Image Transport - Compression requires single channel

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[ERROR] [1395101357.049470140]: Compressed Depth Image Transport - Compression requires single-channel 32bit-floating point or 16bit raw depth images (input format is: mono8).

Rviz does not show the registered point cloud. Running turtlebot software with a create and kinect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141131/error-conpressed-depth-image-transport---compression-requires-single-channel/) by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had requested a topic not in use by openni connected to kinect in rqt and that is why I got the message.  Thanks

---

Originally posted by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) with karma: 101 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0